# Is $(\mathbb{Z}_5, +)$ a semigroup (monoid)?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am to decide whether $(\mathbb{Z}_5, +)$ is a semigroup (monoid) or not. But as far as I understand it $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \{\{0,5,10,\ldots\},\{1,6,\ldots\},\ldots,\{4,9,\ldots\}\}$ (its elements are sets) and $+$ is not defined for sets. Am I right when I think this problem makes no sense?

Comment: What is a semimonoid?

Comment: Should read 'monoid' let me correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right to wonder. However, in this specific case, we usually write $+$ when we mean "the operation inherited from $(\Bbb Z, +)$". It turns out that if you take any element of $\{1, 6, 11,\ldots\}$ and add to any element of $\{3, 8, 13,\ldots\}$, you always get some element of $\{4, 9, 14,\ldots\}$. This is the operation that the $+$ in $(\Bbb Z_5, +)$ signifies. It is not the same $+$ as in $(\Bbb Z, +)$, but the two are so closely related that most people do not differentiate between them notationally.

Answer (score 3):

No, you are not right. First of all $\{0,5,10,\dots\}$ is *not* an element of $\mathbb{Z}_5$; $\{\dots,-10,-5,0,5,10,\dots\}$ is.

Besides, yes, you *can* sum sets:$$A+B=\{a+b\,|\,a\in A\text{ and }b\in B\}.$$

But the usual way of defining $+$ on $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is this $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$, where$$[c]=\{m\in\mathbb Z\,:\,5\mid m-c\}
.$$